How to store the text contents of an element to a variable and log to console?
import { test, expect } from '@playwright/test';

test('test', async ({ page }) => {
  await page.goto('https://www.exploretock.com/whisperingvine4thstreet/');
  await expect(page.getByText('guests')).toBeVisible();
  const guests = await page.getByText('guests');
  const text = guests.innerText;
  console.log(text);
  
});

I am trying to output the contents of the page.getByText('guests') so I can see perform actions depending on what number it is. How do I do this? I've never used typescript before
I was expecting the console to output the text inside which is '2 guests', but it outputs [AsyncFunction: innerText]. I searched for some possible solutions but nothing I tried worked.

The .textContent() action lets you access the text:
const text = await page.getByText("guests").textContent();
console.log(text);

Note that we're awaiting the action, not the locator.
There's also .allTextContents() if you have multiple elements to extract text from, and page.getByText("guests", {exact: true}) can be handy if the default substring match doesn't make sense for your use case.
If you're writing a test, it's better to use a web-first assertion:
await expect(page.getByText("guests")).toHaveText(/\d guests/);

Of course, since we're selecting by text, we already know the text (more or less), so it's somewhat of a pointless assertion. This would be more common if you're selecting by something other than text, like test id, aria role, etc.
If you want to assert that an element with text exists, and you have no other selection constraints, you can use:
await expect(page.getByText("guests")).toBeVisible(); // or `.toBeAttached()`

Note also that the page you're automating blocks headless browsing, so humanize the user-agent and/or run headfully with npx playwright test --headed.
Here's a minimal, runnable example (just add your URL):
import {expect, test} from "@playwright/test"; // ^1.42.1

const url = "<Your URL>";
const userAgent =
  "Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/123.0.0.0 Safari/537.36";

test.describe("with user agent", () => {
  test.use({userAgent});

  test("has 'guests' text", async ({page}) => {
    await page.goto(url, {waitUntil: "commit"});

    const text = await page.getByText("guests").textContent();
    console.log(text); // => 2 guests

    await expect(page.getByText("guests")).toHaveText(/\d guests/);
    await expect(page.getByText("guests")).toBeVisible(); // or `.toBeAttached()`
  });
});

Output:
$ npx playwright test pw.test.js

Running 1 test using 1 worker

  ✓  1 pw.test.js:9:7 › with user agent › has 'guests' text (882ms)
2 guests

  1 passed (1.3s)


Unfortunately this isn’t working for me. When trying to log the variable text to the console, I get the same Async Function output. The best I’ve gotten is an output with [Promise] and I don’t know how to handle that. The playwright header is actually very helpful though, I noticed I was getting blocked by a Cloudflare challenge and that explains why!

Thanks for the response. The test works fine for me so you might still be doing something wrong in your code. If you're having trouble adapting my snippets, I added a fully runnable example--please try running it and let me know if it works for you.

This seems perfectly valid answer to me.

@ggorlen just ran again and its working now, thanks
